# Use the result of a procedure for further conditions?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a procedure that fetches me two columns, who contain the respective symmetric key name and the certificate name, needed to decrypt the passwords in another table. It's working perfectly fine. I get my results and that is working so far.

The "fetching" procedure looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [fetch_data] 

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT [KeyName], [CertName] FROM [Group]

INNER JOIN LT_Groups ON [Group].GroupId = LT_Groups.GroupId 

INNER JOIN Verify ON Verify.UserID = LT_Groups.UserId AND VERIFY.USERNAME = 
CURRENT_USER

END

GO

EXEC fetch_data
```

Now I want to write another procedure, that is supposed to work with the results of the first one. I just don't get how I can use the result of my "fetching_data" in another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define **TempTable** and then Store **Executed** first Stored Procedure **result** in it Like below:

```
INSERT INTO #YourTable
EXEC SP
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is `insert-exec`, but it does have some issues. If the columns output from the inserted procedure ever change, you will get an error. There are other potential issues as well, see the included reference for more.

insert-exec example:

```
create table #fetch_data (keyname varchar(32), certname varchar(32));
insert into #fetch_data
  exec dbo.fetch_data
```

Alternatives to insert-exec are using table-valued functions, sharing a temp table, global temp tables, and table-valued parameters.

Reference

- [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Answer (score 0):

A [table-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine#a-nametvfa-table-valued-functions) might be more appropriate than an [store procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/stored-procedures-database-engine), in this case.

Table-valued functions can be called from the [from clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) of other queries, making the values they return readily available.

**Example**

```
-- Defines table-valued function.
CREATE FUNCTION fetch_data ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    -- Get detiails.
    SELECT 
        [KeyName], 
        [CertName] 
    FROM 
        [Group]
        INNER JOIN LT_Groups    ON  [Group].GroupId = LT_Groups.GroupId 
        INNER JOIN Verify       ON  Verify.UserID   = LT_Groups.UserId 
                                AND VERIFY.USERNAME = CURRENT_USER
);
GO


-- Using table-valued function.
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    fetch_data()
;
```